# Ошибка cannot load certificate NGINX

Tags: nginx, letsencrypt

Проблема следующая, установил сертификаты sudo certbot --nginx
Но при проверке nginx -t выдается след сообщение -

```
75902#75902: cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/site.xyz/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/site.xyz/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib)
```

Как решается такая проблема ?

Comment: а вы запускаете nginx под root юзером?

Comment: пользователь, от имени которого запущен nginx, должен иметь разрешение на чтение сертификата (и всех каталогов пути)

Comment: @nörbörnënа как получить это разрешение?

Comment: @Komdosh вообще все команды nginx я исполняю с sudo

Comment: хорошо, видимо нужно выполнить требование, чтобы папка в которой лежит ваш сертификат имела права доступа 700, сами файлы должны быть с правами 600, и папка и файлы должны принадлежать юзеру root

Comment: @Komdosh а как это делается, я пока не хорошо во всем этом разбираюсь ? chmod 700  ?

Comment: `sudo chown -R root:root /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.xyz` `sudo chmod 700 /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.xyz` `sudo chmod 600 /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.xyz/*`

Comment: помогло или всё также?

Comment: Ошибка исправилась иным путем - сам не очень понял, но я просто обновил сертификаты и домен нормально стал запускаться, при всем при том, что строка ошибки осталась  если тестировать nginx. Спасибо

Comment: *Но при проверке nginx -t* — `sudo nginx -t`